# find command and support for media metadata

Tags: linux, bash, find, metadata, file-search

I have a folder with tons of disorganized files of all types with deep levels of subfolders and I want to find every audio file WITH 320kpbs (bitrate) and run something upon each of them without moving them all to the same place in order to do so. Something like:

`find /some/folder -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(flac|ape|wa?v|m(p3|4a))' -BITRATE_IS_320kbps -exec ... \;`

But I know no command line which could do this kind of task for me.

I've already thought of some less elegant ways to achieve this, but I still want to know how to `find` (maybe something alike) files by metadata like this?

Comment: if you have a command that tests for the bitrate you could use that in `-exec` since the exit code of that is used to decide if that file is in fact a mach or not (exit code 0 means it's a match, anything else is no match)

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196890/how-to-find-the-bitrate-of-an-mp3-file-via-command-line) post has some options to extract the bitrate from an audio file. Once you have that, you can use its output and some shell script to compare it to 320 and do something with the file.

Comment: In the Explorer, you can search for *, add the column 'Bit rate' in the display, and sort by it. That allows you to select exactly those files.

Comment: About Eric's comment, an example would be nice... and blm's suggestion is basically what my not so elegant way to solve this consisted of...

Comment: Does it have to be with the `find` utility? It seems useful, just not familiar with the syntax yet. I'm still pretty new to `bash` and this seemed like a good exercise so I started putting something together for ya..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the information from @blm's linked answer you could do something like:

```
find /some/folder -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(flac|ape|wa?v|m(p3|4a))' -exec bash -c " file '{}' | grep '320 kbps'" \; -exec <do what you want>
```

the first `-exec` will look for only files that are 320 kbps, since the `file` command reports that for us.  If the `grep` does not match anything then that `-exec` will be false and the second `-exec` will not be executed.  If `grep` does match though then the second `-exec` will be executed

For completeness, this feature of `-exec` can be found in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

> ```
> -exec command ;  
>      Execute command; true if 0 status is returned
> ```

**Edit:**

Regarding to the use of `file` in this solution, it appears to not work for everyone. So here is an alternative way to get the bitrate using `mediainfo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

bitrate=$(mediainfo "$1" | grep -Ei 'overall bit ?rate.*[[:digit:]]+.*$' | grep -Eo [[:digit:]]+)
echo $bitrate
```

You can save it in a .sh file with execution permission, then it'll give you the file's bitrate (digits only) according to `mediainfo` Overall Bitrate information, in a way you can replace

`-exec bash -c " file '{}' | grep '320 kbps'" \;`

with

`-exec bash -c "BITRATE_SCRIPT_PATH '{}' | grep '320'" \;`

(may behave badly with lossless audio files, which tend to have 1Mbps+ of bitrate)

Comment: Let me clarify this to myself...`find` evaluates  `-exec`ed commands returning a non-zero value as any other test option giving a `false`?

Comment: @PedroVernetti Right

Comment: Nice to know... I've read `find` manpages some times, but have never put my eyes at this piece of information. Thank you

Comment: As pointed in @JayC 's answer, `file` don't give me the desired information. Actually it gives me almost no information at all. So I'm going to append my bitrate checking script in your answer.

Comment: @PedroVernetti You may want to use `mediainfo` to get the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you manage to get bitrate information from the `file` cmd but I don't..

```
$: file 01\ -\ Trolleyed.flac
01 - Trolleyed.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 24 bit, stereo, 17842272 samples

$: file 01\ -\ Autumn\ Leaves.mp3
01 - Autumn Leaves.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0
```

In any case, inspired by this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187088/if-command-in-find-exec) i've come up with a solution that requires an external tool (in this case [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)). It's not as sexy or performant is I'd like it but it works.

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(flac|ape|wa?v|m(p3|4a))' -exec sh -c 'for x; do export BITRATE=$(mediainfo --inform="Audio;%BitRate%" "$x"); if [ $BITRATE = 320000 ]; then echo "$x"; fi; done' _ {} +
```

Here the `then` statement simply echoes the filename but could be replaced by anything else really.

Merry  Xmas to you all..

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this may be a common problem. I had to think my own workaround for this too, which I've now shared via edit on the accepted answer.